# Playing sound on activity start

Tags: android

I am one activity that is started when it receives some data from server.
To be clear, when new work is available for driver, the screen pops in the application. 
Is there any way to notify user of this screen with sound.

The code for the activity is follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using NorthStar.Driver.Application;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Requests;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Results;

namespace NorthStar.Driver
{
    [Activity(Label = "New Work Available")]
    public class NewWorkAvailableActivity : Activity
    {
        public string driverId;
        public string bookingId;
        public string fullAddress;
        public string customerPhoneNumber;

        private Timer jobTimer;
        private int timerCount = 9;
        private TextView jobTimerLabel;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NewJobAvailable);

            fullAddress = Intent.GetStringExtra("fullAddress");
            customerPhoneNumber = Intent.GetStringExtra("customerPhoneNumber");
            driverId = Intent.GetStringExtra("driverID");
            bookingId = Intent.GetStringExtra("bookingId");

            TextView jobLocationLabel = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.newJobLocation);
            jobLocationLabel.Text = string.Format("at {0}", Intent.GetStringExtra("jobLocation"));

            jobTimerLabel = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.newJobTimerText);

            Button acceptBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AcceptWorkBtn);
            acceptBtn.Click += (sender, args) =>
                                   {
                                       jobTimer.Stop();
                                       AcceptBookingAsync asyncTask = new AcceptBookingAsync(this);
                                       asyncTask.Execute();

                                   };

            Button rejectBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.RejectWorkBtn);
            rejectBtn.Click += (sender, args) => { Close(); };

            jobTimer = new Timer(1000);
            jobTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
                                    {
                                        CheckTimer();

                                    };
            jobTimer.Start();


            // Create your application here
        }


        private void Close()
        {
            jobTimer.Stop();
            Intent a = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            a.PutExtra("driverID", driverId);
            a.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            StartActivity(a);
        }

        private void CheckTimer()
        {
            if(timerCount == 0)
            {
                //timeout so return home
                Close();
            }
            else
            {
                timerCount--;
                RunOnUiThread(() => { jobTimerLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} seconds to respond", timerCount); });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I have tried this But it doesn't work when the screen is called.**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);


            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NewJobAvailable);

            string ns = Context.NotificationService;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(ApplicationContext);
            Notification notification = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.Icon, "NorthStar Taxi");
            notification.Defaults |= NotificationDefaults.All;
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NewWorkAvailableActivity));
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);


            fullAddress = Intent.GetStringExtra("fullAddress");
            customerPhoneNumber = Intent.GetStringExtra("customerPhoneNumber");
            driverId = Intent.GetStringExtra("driverID");
            bookingId = Intent.GetStringExtra("bookingId");
```

Comment: you have to do something with this notificationmanager and this notification.

Comment: what do you mean by something???

Comment: ok got it, was missing to call the notification..

Comment: you could also use a MediaPlayer to play a sound file.